# using object in place of ID with Rails 3.1 create call

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm using Rails 3.1.3 and Ruby 1.9.2, and I'm running into what seems like a bug when creating seed data in my database. I'm creating a simple wine collection app, and I have a `Grape` class with just two simple instances (`name` is "red" or "white"). I have a `Varietal` class which `belongs_to` the `Grape` class and also has just a simple `name` field.

When I go to create some seed data, I use code like the following:

```
# create some reds
r = Grape.find_or_create_by_name('Red')
Varietal.find_or_create_by_name_and_grape_id('Cabernet Franc', r)
Varietal.find_or_create_by_name_and_grape_id('Cabernet Sauvignon', r)
Varietal.find_or_create_by_name_and_grape_id('Malbec', r)

# create some whites
w = Grape.find_or_create_by_name('White')
Varietal.find_or_create_by_name_and_grape_id('Chardonnay', w)
Varietal.find_or_create_by_name_and_grape_id('Riesling', w)
Varietal.find_or_create_by_name_and_grape_id('Sauvignon Blanc', w)
```

Strangely, when I go look at the data in the database, *all* of the `Varietals` are associated with the "red" `Grape`. Using the Rails console, I figured out that if I pass the `id` field from the found `Grape` instance rather than the instance itself, I get the correct behavior.

Am I missing something? I thought in Rails you could always pass an ActiveRecord object in place of the raw ID, and it would lookup the `id` field value automatically.

Comment: I think if you explicitly use dynamic finder by_grape_id then it expects from you to pass ID.

Comment: If that's true, then why does a find_by_grape_id with the white Grape instance work just fine? Also, I noticed that the SQL executed for the find_or_create first does the correct SELECT with the ID of the white Grape instance, but the INSERT to create the Varietal has the wrong ID. Still seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can normall pass objects instead of IDs but that tends to be more on the routing and associations.

You are asking it to find by **name** and **grape_id**, but passing in a name and a grape *instance*, which is where the problem lies.

If you stipulate the id in the finder, you need to pass in the ID.

Answer (score 0):

`r` and `w` should return `Grape` objects, right? So can't you access their `id` elements like this?

```
# save grape stuff by entering the ID instead of the object
# create some reds
r = Grape.find_or_create_by_name('Red')
Varietal.find_or_create_by_name_and_grape_id('Cabernet Franc', r.id)
Varietal.find_or_create_by_name_and_grape_id('Cabernet Sauvignon', r.id)
Varietal.find_or_create_by_name_and_grape_id('Malbec', r.id)

# create some whites
w = Grape.find_or_create_by_name('White')
Varietal.find_or_create_by_name_and_grape_id('Chardonnay', w.id)
Varietal.find_or_create_by_name_and_grape_id('Riesling', w.id)
Varietal.find_or_create_by_name_and_grape_id('Sauvignon Blanc', w.id)
```

This would pass in the id of the grape you selected and would match up with the dynamic finder you are using.